# Auto import for react native is not working on vscode

Tags: reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-code

I am developing a react native application, but no matter what I do the Auto import feature is not working for me on vscode.
Feature I want (if you type , it'll automatically import the Text module from React)
And this is what is happening now, which does not highlight any error for me
[My current problem screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWXGe.png)

I have looked for some similar issues, but none was helpful to me.
I tried fixing my eslint and also added jsconfig, and it did not work.
Any advice would be very appreciated.

eslint.js:

```
module.exports = {
    extends: "airbnb",
    plugins: ["react", "react-native", "react-hooks"],
    parser: "babel-eslint",
    env: {
        jest: true,
        "react-native/react-native": true,
    },
    rules: {
        "no-use-before-define": "off",
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": "off",
        "react/prop-types": "off",
        "comma-dangle": "off",
        "padded-blocks": "off",
        "arrow-body-style": "off",
        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": "warn",
        "react-native/no-unused-styles": 2,
        "react-native/split-platform-components": 2,
        "react-native/no-inline-styles": 2,
        "react-native/no-color-literals": 2,
        "react-native/no-raw-text": 2,
        "react-native/no-single-element-style-arrays": 2,
    },
    globals: {
        fetch: false,
    },
    // Indent with 4 spaces
    indent: ["error", 4],

    // Indent JSX with 4 spaces
    "react/jsx-indent": ["error", 4],

    // Indent props with 4 spaces
    "react/jsx-indent-props": ["error", 4],
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject",
    "lint": "eslint *.js **/*.js src/**/*.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~40.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.3",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "~7.9.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.10.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

babel.config.js:

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
    };
};
```